# Efficiently Drop Rows in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset like:

```
    Id   Status

    1     0
    1     0
    1     0
    1     0
    1     1
    2     0
    1     0 # --> gets removed since this row appears after id 1 already had a status of 1
    2     0
    3     0
    3     0
```

I want to drop all rows of an id after its status became 1, i.e. my new dataset will be:

```
    Id   Status

    1     0
    1     0
    1     0
    1     0
    1     1
    2     0
    2     0
    3     0
    3     0
```

I want to learn how to implement this computation efficiently since I have a very large (200 GB+) dataset.

The solution I currently have is to find the index of the first 1 and slice each group that way. In cases where no 1 exists, return the group unchanged:

```
def remove(series):
    indexless = series.reset_index(drop=True)
    ones = indexless[indexless['Status'] == 1]
    if len(ones) > 0:
        return indexless.iloc[:ones.index[0] + 1]

    else:
        return indexless

df.groupby('Id').apply(remove).reset_index(drop=True)
```

However, this runs very slowly, any way to fix this or to alternatively speed up the computation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First idea is create cumulative sum per groups with boolean mask, but also necessary `shift` for avoid lost first `1`:

```
#pandas 0.24+
s = (df['Status'] == 1).groupby(df['Id']).apply(lambda x: x.shift(fill_value=0).cumsum())
#pandas below
#s = (df['Status'] == 1).groupby(df['Id']).apply(lambda x: x.shift().fillna(0).cumsum())
df = df[s == 0]
print (df)
   Id  Status
0   1       0
1   1       0
2   1       0
3   1       0
4   1       1
5   2       0
7   2       0
8   3       0
9   3       0
```

Another solution is use custom lambda function with [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html):

```
def f(x):
    if x['new'].any():
        return x.iloc[:x['new'].idxmax()+1, :]
    else:
        return x

df1 = (df.assign(new=(df['Status'] == 1))
        .groupby(df['Id'], group_keys=False)
        .apply(f).drop('new', axis=1))
print (df1)
    Id  Status
0    1       0
1    1       0
2    1       0
3    1       0
4    1       1
5    2       0
8    2       0
9    3       0
10   3       0
```

Or a bit modified first solution - filter only groups with `1` and apply solutyion only there:

```
m = df['Status'].eq(1)
ids = df.loc[m, 'Id'].unique()
print (ids)
[1]

m1 = df['Id'].isin(m)
m2 = (m[m1].groupby(df['Id'])
            .apply(lambda x: x.shift(fill_value=0).cumsum())
            .eq(0))

df = df[m2.reindex(df.index, fill_value=True)]
print (df)
    Id  Status
0    1       0
1    1       0
2    1       0
3    1       0
4    1       1
5    2       0
8    2       0
9    3       0
10   3       0
```

Comment: @tstseby - hmm, so `id` is index and `status` is column? My solution working if `id, status` are both columns

Comment: It doesnt really matter though does it? You can set index and then reset once you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with this dataset.

```
l =[[1,0],[1,0],[1,0],[1,0],[1,1],[2,0],[1,0], [2,0], [2,1],[3,0],[2,0], [3,0]]
df_ = pd.DataFrame(l, columns = ['id', 'status'])
```

We will find the status=1 index for each id.

```
status_1_indice = df_[df_['status']==1].reset_index()[['index', 'id']].set_index('id')

    index
id  
1   4
2   8
```

Now we join over `df_` with `status_1_indice`

```
join_table  = df_.join(status_1_indice, on='id').reset_index().fillna(np.inf)
```

Notice `.fillna(np.inf)` for id's that dont have status=1. Result:

```
    level_0 id  status  index
0   0   1   0   4.000000
1   1   1   0   4.000000
2   2   1   0   4.000000
3   3   1   0   4.000000
4   4   1   1   4.000000
5   5   2   0   8.000000
6   6   1   0   4.000000
7   7   2   0   8.000000
8   8   2   1   8.000000
9   9   3   0   inf
10  10  2   0   8.000000
11  11  3   0   inf
```

Required dataframe can be obtained by:

```
join_table.query('level_0 <= index')[['id', 'status']]
```

Together:

```
status_1_indice = df_[df_['status']==1].reset_index()[['index', 'id']].set_index('id')
join_table  = df_.join(status_1_indice, on='id').reset_index().fillna(np.inf)
required_df = join_table.query('level_0 <= index')[['id', 'status']]


   id   status
0   1   0
1   1   0
2   1   0
3   1   0
4   1   1
5   2   0
7   2   0
8   2   1
9   3   0
11  3   0
```

I cant vouch for the performance but this is  more straight forward than the method in question.